# SQL query to fetch list of records in subquery

Tags: sql

How to write query to fetch the record something like this,

I have two tables as mentioned below,

[image]

Now, i want to fetch record for 1 row - list of column dtls as below query

select a.ID AS ID, A.Row_NO as Row_NO, b.* as b  from A a, B b

Please help me to fetch records based on my requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [LEFT JOIN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp) or [INNER JOIN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp) (see links for documentation)

```
SELECT i.ID as ID, i.Row_NO as Row_NO, j.* AS j FROM A AS i 
LEFT JOIN B AS j 
ON i.Row_NO = j.Row_NO
```

btw this query would be easier readable if you don't use capital letters in your table structure

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT
   a.ID AS ID,
   a.Row_NO as Row_NO,
   b.ID AS bID,
   b.Col_No,
   b.Value 
FROM A a
INNER JOIN B b ON (b.Row_No = a.Row_No);
```